# Visual Studio 2010 SP1 setup project doesn't install SP1 of Visual C++ 2010 Runtime Libraries

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, setup-project

I'm using VS 2010 SP1 and I've created a VS setup project to install my app. My app uses a DLL written in C++ so I need to include the VC++ 2010 Runtime Libraries.

One of my users reported getting an error while running my installer and I traced it down to the fact that this user already has the SP1 version of the VC++ 2010 Runtime Library installed. My installer tried to install the non-SP1 version and then quit when it saw a newer version already installed (the SP1 version).
[image: screenshot of error]
[image: screenshot of error]

I've confirmed this is the source of the problem here: http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en/crm/thread/db84d4c3-c58e-4ff9-997f-f4e0116bf043 and http://notepad.patheticcockroach.com/1666/installing-visual-c-2010-and-windows-sdk-for-windows-7-offline-installer-and-installation-troubleshooting/

It seems like the only workaround for users is to uninstall the SP1 runtime library and then run my installer. Obviously this is not ideal so I'm looking for a better solution.

The only one I've come up with is to tell my VS setup project to download the runtime library from Microsoft's SP1 link instead (http://download.microsoft.com/download/C/6/D/C6D0FD4E-9E53-4897-9B91-836EBA2AACD3/vcredist_x86.exe). I'm a little worried because this feels like a hack. Anyone have any better ideas?

If it's helpful, here's the install log from the user who hit this bug:

```
The following properties have been set:
Property: [AdminUser] = true {boolean}
Property: [InstallMode] = HomeSite {string}
Property: [ProcessorArchitecture] = AMD64 {string}
Property: [VersionNT] = 6.1.1 {version}
Running checks for package 'Windows Installer 3.1', phase BuildList
The following properties have been set for package 'Windows Installer 3.1':
Running checks for command 'WindowsInstaller3_1\WindowsInstaller-KB893803-v2-x86.exe'
Result of running operator 'VersionGreaterThanOrEqualTo' on property 'VersionMsi' and value '3.1': true
Result of checks for command 'WindowsInstaller3_1\WindowsInstaller-KB893803-v2-x86.exe' is 'Bypass'
'Windows Installer 3.1' RunCheck result: No Install Needed
Running checks for package 'Visual C++ 2010 Runtime Libraries (x86)', phase BuildList
Running MsiProductCheck with ProductCode '{196BB40D-1578-3D01-B289-BEFC77A11A1E}'
MsiQueryProductState returned '-1'
Setting value '-1 {int}' for property 'VCRedistInstalled'
The following properties have been set for package 'Visual C++ 2010 Runtime Libraries (x86)':
Property: [VCRedistInstalled] = -1 {int}
Running checks for command 'vcredist_x86\vcredist_x86.exe'
Result of running operator 'ValueGreaterThanEqualTo' on property 'VCRedistInstalled' and value '3': false
Result of running operator 'ValueEqualTo' on property 'AdminUser' and value 'false': false
Skipping FailIf because Property 'Version9X' was not defined
Result of running operator 'VersionLessThan' on property 'VersionNT' and value '5.00': false
Result of checks for command 'vcredist_x86\vcredist_x86.exe' is 'Install'
'Visual C++ 2010 Runtime Libraries (x86)' RunCheck result: Install Needed
Running checks for package 'Microsoft .NET Framework 4 Client Profile (x86 and x64)', phase BuildList
Reading value 'Version' of registry key 'HKLM\Software\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Client'
Read string value '4.0.30319'
Setting value '4.0.30319 {string}' for property 'DotNet40Client_TargetVersion'
The following properties have been set for package 'Microsoft .NET Framework 4 Client Profile (x86 and x64)':
Property: [DotNet40Client_TargetVersion] = 4.0.30319 {string}
Running checks for command 'DotNetFX40Client\dotNetFx40_Client_x86_x64.exe'
Result of running operator 'ValueEqualTo' on property 'InstallMode' and value 'HomeSite': true
Result of checks for command 'DotNetFX40Client\dotNetFx40_Client_x86_x64.exe' is 'Bypass'
Running checks for command 'DotNetFX40Client\dotNetFx40_Client_setup.exe'
Result of running operator 'ValueNotEqualTo' on property 'InstallMode' and value 'HomeSite': false
Result of running operator 'VersionGreaterThanOrEqualTo' on property 'DotNet40Client_TargetVersion' and value '4.0.30129': true
Result of checks for command 'DotNetFX40Client\dotNetFx40_Client_setup.exe' is 'Bypass'
'Microsoft .NET Framework 4 Client Profile (x86 and x64)' RunCheck result: No Install Needed
Installation of components 'Visual C++ 2010 Runtime Libraries (x86)' was accepted.
Copying files to temporary directory "C:\Users\JAGDISH\AppData\Local\Temp\VSD653B.tmp\"
Downloading files to "C:\Users\JAGDISH\AppData\Local\Temp\VSD653B.tmp\"
(14-12-2011 14:03:32) Downloading 'vcredist_x86\vcredist_x86.exe' from 'http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=177916&clcid=0x409' to 'C:\Users\JAGDISH\AppData\Local\Temp\VSD653B.tmp\'
Download completed at 14-12-2011 14:05:00
Verifying file integrity of C:\Users\JAGDISH\AppData\Local\Temp\VSD653B.tmp\vcredist_x86\vcredist_x86.exe
WinVerifyTrust returned 0
File trusted
Running checks for package 'Visual C++ 2010 Runtime Libraries (x86)', phase BeforePackage
Running MsiProductCheck with ProductCode '{196BB40D-1578-3D01-B289-BEFC77A11A1E}'
MsiQueryProductState returned '-1'
Setting value '-1 {int}' for property 'VCRedistInstalled'
The following properties have been set for package 'Visual C++ 2010 Runtime Libraries (x86)':
Property: [VCRedistInstalled] = -1 {int}
Running checks for command 'vcredist_x86\vcredist_x86.exe'
Result of running operator 'ValueGreaterThanEqualTo' on property 'VCRedistInstalled' and value '3': false
Result of running operator 'ValueEqualTo' on property 'AdminUser' and value 'false': false
Skipping FailIf because Property 'Version9X' was not defined
Result of running operator 'VersionLessThan' on property 'VersionNT' and value '5.00': false
Result of checks for command 'vcredist_x86\vcredist_x86.exe' is 'Install'
'Visual C++ 2010 Runtime Libraries (x86)' RunCheck result: Install Needed
Verifying file integrity of C:\Users\JAGDISH\AppData\Local\Temp\VSD653B.tmp\vcredist_x86\vcredist_x86.exe
WinVerifyTrust returned 0
File trusted
Installing using command 'C:\Users\JAGDISH\AppData\Local\Temp\VSD653B.tmp\vcredist_x86\vcredist_x86.exe' and parameters ' /q:a '
Process exited with code 5100
Status of package 'Visual C++ 2010 Runtime Libraries (x86)' after install is 'InstallFailed'
```

Answer (score 0):

Predefined prerequisites in Visual Studio setup projects are not very good. The fact that they are rarely updated is also a problem.

So the best solution is to create your own custom prerequisite. Visual Studio setup projects do not support custom prerequisite creation. However, it can be done by manually generating the [required manifests](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229223%28VS.80%29.aspx).

These manifests can be generated automatically with the [Bootstrapper Manifest Generator tool](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/bmg).

After generating the package manifests, you can add all these files (including the package) in a separate folder in the Visual Studio prerequisites folder, for example:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bootstrapper\Packages
```

This way you can select the prerequisite in your setup project property pages.

Your custom prerequisite can detect both the original runtime and the SP1. You can find the SP1 detection criteria here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2010/05/05/10008146.aspx

Comment: The 'detection criteria' is precisely what doesn't work.  Somebody's installer got to that machine first and just copied msvcr100.dll to c:\windows\system32.  Because that's easy.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by adding the target output of my c++ DLL to the setup project. Once I did this, the setup project automatically bundled the appropriate c++ dll's with my installer and now everything runs fine.

The original problem was caused by the fact that I had manually checked "C++ Runtime libraries" in the setup project's prerequisites.

@Cosmin Pirvu -- your solution may work, but this is what I ended up doing.